# Hooking into product_variation_linked action to modify variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I want to add the parent price to all variations using "Create variations from all attributes > go"
- but when I add action it won't even show my debug echo text.

I'm trying to add an action to this hook

> do_action( 'product_variation_linked', $variation_id );

Here: public function create_all_product_variations
in this file: class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php line 1189

Instead of echoing my debug text it just messes up the alert confirmation and doesn't allow the created variations to show using Ajax. They are created though. They display fine on refresh.

Any idea why the hook doesn't operate as one would expect?
I guess it has something do do with Ajax?

I guess plan B is to write a function that updates all variations. Could also generate the variations after import too and bypass the whole product > go GUI?

Thanks

Comment: The hook you are trying to use is just for **grouped products** and has nothing to do with altering variation prices from a variation product.

Comment: copy/pasted the name of the next file in the list accidentally - corrected now.